# Types of Unbalancable Chemical Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am creating a program that, given a reaction, will balance it(Using system of linear equations and a matrix). However, there are some equations that cannot be balanced and there are two types that I have encountered so far.

1. Reactions that are impossible such as (H2O + NO2 -> HNO3)
2. Reactions that have multiple solutions such as (H2 + C7H8O2 -> C6H6O + CH4 + H2O) or (C6H6 + O2 -> CO2 + CO + C + H2O)

I want to display in my program why a reaction can't be balanced. Is there a way to tell either type of reaction with an algorithm? On online chemical reaction balancers, they are able to differentiate between them.

Comment: Related on Chem SE: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/simplest-way-to-balance-any-chemical-equation

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/145933/755, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/159801, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4311049/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 4):

The way you balance them in the first place is to solve a linear system. For example that first equation can be described by the system $2a=c,a+2b=3c,b=c$, describing balance of H atoms, O atoms, and N atoms respectively. This system can be rewritten in matrix form as

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

The balance is "unambiguous" in the sense of chemistry if the kernel (another term for the same thing is "null space") of this matrix is one dimensional. This means that the solution of this system has one free variable and specifying the value of the free variable tells you the values of the others. This makes sense in the context of chemistry because the free variable lets you scale the reaction up or down, but if there is only one free variable then this is the only ambiguity in the system.

For the other possibilities, the system is inconsistent in the sense of chemistry if the kernel is zero dimensional (in which case the only way for the atoms to balance is for all the coefficients to be zero, which *is* balanced, but it doesn't mean anything in real life). The system is ambiguous in the sense of chemistry if the kernel has dimension greater than 1.

The conventional algorithm for getting the dimension of the kernel in exact arithmetic is Gaussian elimination. In common situations in chemistry this can be done in rational number arithmetic (without encountering problems with huge denominators). With larger problems you might use floating point arithmetic, and for that it is generally less prone to numerical error if you use a method based on the singular value decomposition (SVD) instead of Gaussian elimination.

By the way, the minimum dimension of the kernel is $n-\min \{ m,n \}$ where $n$ is the number of variables and $m$ is the number of equations. Consequently there is always some nontrivial solution as long as there are more species than there are types of atoms to balance, and the balance is always ambiguous if there are at least 2 more species than there are types of atoms to balance. You can use this rule to determine that both of your #2 examples were going to be ambiguous, since they have $(m,n)=(3,5)$ and $(m,n)=(3,6)$ respectively.

Comment: The system is not inconsistent in the traditional sense if it has the trivial (0) solution.

Comment: @TedShifrin That is true, I clarified.